# only getting highlightling with python plugin for vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using vs code for writing some python. On a ubuntu 20.04 machine.

I have the python plugin installed.
I set the python plugin to point on my python installation at

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

The issue is that currently, the only support I have for programming, is color highlighting of the code. There is no intellisense at all, and no info-boxes pop up when I hover the mouse.
My settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3.8",
    "window.zoomLevel": -1
}
```

From vs code docs,(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) I can read that I should be able to turn on linting by hitting ctrl+shift+P and going to 'Python: Select Interpreter'.
However when I type in "python" the only option that appears, is "Jupyter: convert a notebook to python script"

**Proposed fix**

One fix, could be to make sure that the python interpreter is pointing to the right place.
So if I run:

```
ask@garser:/usr/bin$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

which is then a symbolic link for:

```
ask@garser:/usr/bin$ file python3.8
python3.8: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=6219948c928370db236e7a182b13d2e180e5e6c0, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

So that part should be fine?

Does anyone have an idea why this does not work?

Comment: which Python extension do you have

Comment: The completely standard one called "Python"

Comment: if you don't mention the full name and version and which language server (Microsoft, PyLance, Jeti) we need to guess

Comment: name and version of vs code? and what is a language server, and where do I find it?

Comment: on the page of the extension, and setting `python.languageServer`

Comment: I can't really find anything that correponds to that. The plugin is made by 'ms-python.python'

Comment: the version in the corner is v2021.4.765268190

Comment: go to the settings and search for `server`, try the different version